# Determine the unit of raw number expressions that also convert between units

Tags: units, unit-conversion

In a program code that calculates physical quantities while omitting their units, I found the following calculation:

```
length   = ...                         # in mm (!)
velocity = ...                         # in m/s
time     = (length / velocity) / 1000  # in s
```

Because `length` was not in standard units, I wondered if the `/ 1000` was the correct way to convert the result to seconds.

#### Autor's thought process for writing the calculation

To get `time` in standard units, do not use `length` but use `(length/1000)` instead. As the latter is in standard units, everything should work out. Afterwards, I can simplify the expression:

```
  (length/1000) / velocity
= length / (velocity * 1000)
= (length / velocity) / 1000
```

This is akin to a *constructive* proof.

#### My thought process for determining the result's unit

As a reader I had a different approach. On a piece of paper, I inserted $1 \mathit{Unit}$ for each variable and computed the result to see if it was in $m/s$. Obviously, I had to do something with the `1000` too, so I replaced `1000` by $m/\mathit{mm}$ because $\frac{m}{\mathit{mm}}=\frac{1000\mathit{mm}}{1\mathit{mm}} = \frac{1000}{1} = 1000$. This resulted in

$$
  \frac{\;\frac{\tt{length}}{\tt{velocity}}\;}{m/mm}
= \frac{\;\frac{mm}{m/s}\;}{\frac{m}{mm}}
= \frac{\;\frac{s \cdot \mathit{mm}^2}{m}\;}{m}
= \frac{s \cdot \left(\frac{m}{1000}\right)^2}{m^2}
= \frac{\frac{s \cdot m^2}{1000^2}}{m^2}
= \frac{s}{1000^2}
= \frac{s}{1\,000\,000}
= 1\, ns
$$

Where did I go wrong, and how do I correctly type check calculations like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that units are just specific quantities, and that the numerical value of a quantity (that is, a pure number which can be stored in a computer's memory) can be obtained by dividing that quantity by a corresponding unit. So, start with the relationship

$$t = \frac{l}{v}$$

and if you want the time in seconds, divide by second

$$t/\mathrm{s} = \frac{l}{v\cdot\mathrm{s}}$$

Then, dividing both the numerator and the denominator by millimeter yields

$$t/\mathrm{s} = \frac{l/\mathrm{mm}}{v\cdot\mathrm{s}/\mathrm{mm}}$$

And, finally, multiplying and dividing at the denominator by the wanted speed unit yields

$$\begin{align}t/\mathrm{s} &= \frac{l/\mathrm{mm}}{v/(\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s})\cdot (\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s})\cdot\mathrm{s}/\mathrm{mm}} \\
&= \frac{l/\mathrm{mm}}{v/(\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s})\cdot \mathrm{m}/\mathrm{mm}} \\ 
&= \frac{l/\mathrm{mm}}{v/(\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s})\times 1000}\end{align}$$

The last line above corresponds to the last equation in your code. Or you can operate the other way round, starting from the equation in the code:

$$\frac{l/\mathrm{mm}}{v/(\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s})\times 1000} = \frac{t}{\mathrm{s}\times 1000\,\mathrm{mm}/\mathrm{m}} = t/\mathrm{s}$$

Note that even though the variable name in the code is `length`, it contains the numerical value $l/\mathrm{mm}$ and the variable `velocity` contains the numerical value $v/(\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s})$. The result gives the numerical value $t/\mathrm{s}$, that is, the time measured in seconds.

[Quantity calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantity_calculus) is the key to solve all these kind of problems!

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question. *"start with the relationship t=l/v"* and *"if you want the time in seconds"* indicate, that you wrote this answer for the programmer in above question. But the question was about the perspective of a reader. Is this formulation better?: *Given a set of variables, their units, and a expression that omits those units but may also convert units, **determine the resulting unit**.*

Comment: @Socowi I edited the question to also do that, see second last paragraph.

Comment: That's more like it, although the expected result should be a unit (e.g. `1s` or `1ms`) and not a dimension like `t/s`. The question is about determining units (i.e. dimension **and scale**). To this end, you'd also have to explain the step from `1000` to `1000mm/m` in detail.

Comment: @Socowi $t/\mathrm{s}$ is _not_ a dimension: it's the value of the quantity $t$ divided by second, that is, the numerical value of $t$ when expressed in seconds. This gives you implicitly the unit.

Comment: Oh right. Thank you for clarifying this. So `... = t/s` can be read as *"the result of ... is a time/duration measured in seconds"*? That's great! If you add those explanations to your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Socowi Those explanations are already in the answer. I won't drop the first part because it can be useful also to others: answers should be useful for a larger public, and the first part tells you how to construct the code from a quantity equation ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You replaced only a part of the conversion **factor**.

The author converted using the factor `1/1000`. When type checking, you have to replace that entire conversion factor. $1 / (mm/s)$ would yield the correct result of $1\,s$.

#### General approach for type checking raw number expression

1. Spot the constant numbers from which you *think* that they are used for unit conversion, for example:

   - powers of ten (10, 100, 1000, ... and 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, ...)
   - constants for time, e.g. 365, 24, 60, 3600
   - constants for angles, e.g. 360, 180, 90; $\pi$, $\tau$; 400, 200, 100
   - and a huge load of other constants in case you have to deal with the imperial system
2. Rewrite the expression so that the numbers from step 1 are written as separate factors in front of everything else, e.g.
   $$1000\cdot\frac{1}{3600}\cdot\ldots\cdot(\text{ expression without unit conversion })$$
3. Replace each of the extracted numbers by equivalent fractions of units. The numerator is the output unit and the denominator is input unit of the conversion, e.g.
   $$(\mathrm{km}/\mathrm m)\cdot \frac{1}{(\mathrm h/\mathrm s)}\cdot\ldots\cdot(\text{ expression without unit conversion })$$
4. For each variable insert $1\,\mathrm{Unit}$ and calculate the result.

Answer (score 0):

If we use [square brackets] as an operator that means "the units of," we have

$$
\left[
\frac{\tt{length}}{\tt{velocity}}
\right]
= 
\frac{\text{mm}}{\text{m/s}}
= \text{s}\frac{\text{mm}}{\text{m}}
$$

We know that $\rm 1000\,mm = 1\,m$, or equivalently that $\frac{1\,\mathrm{m}}{1000\,\mathrm{mm}} = 1$. And we can multiply or divide by one without changing the value of our expression. So we can say

$$
\mathrm s \frac{\mathrm{mm}}{\mathrm m}
=
\mathrm s \frac{\mathrm{mm}}{\mathrm m} \times 1
=
\mathrm s \frac{\mathrm{mm}}{\mathrm m}
\times \frac{1\,\mathrm m}{1000\,\mathrm{mm}}
$$

This is exactly equivalent to, but sloppier than, the approach in Massimo's answer of writing $\frac{v}{\mathrm{m/s}}$ to refer to the numerical value of $v$ in some specific unit.
The notation "$\mathit{variable}/\mathrm{unit}$" is specifically encouraged by the BIPM, which defines the SI unit standard.
However, as a practical matter, I find that the formal approach produces enough denominators-in-denominators that I have to do a handstand about them; handstands are not among my skills. My approach is convenient if you are working on a piece of paper, where you might write something like

\begin{align}
\ell &= 7\,\mathrm{mm}
\\
v &= 10\,\mathrm{m/s}
\\
t = \frac\ell v 
&= \frac{7\,\mathrm{mm}}{10\,\mathrm{m/s}}
\color{lightgray}{\times 1}
\\
&= \frac{7\,\mathrm{mm}}{10\,\mathrm{m/s}}
\color{lightgray}{\times\frac{1\,\mathrm m}{1000\,\mathrm{mm}}} = 7\times10^{-4}\,\mathrm s
\end{align}

In this approach your unit conversion is "done" when all the units you dislike are, algebraically, cancelled out.  So if you are converting a volume you would multiply or divide by
$1^3 = \left(\frac{1\,\mathrm{m}}{1000\,\mathrm{mm}}\right)^3$